# Dynamic Computation in Tableau based on User Input

Tags: tableau-api

I have a requirement to dynamically perform computations in Tableau based on User Input.

For this purpose my basic query looks something like this:

```
Select some_dimension,sum(some_measure)/count(some_measure) as 
some_measure_average
from table
where date = User_Input
group by some_dimension
```

The User_Input value should be passed based on what the user has selected and the corresponding computation should be performed based on the above query logic.Here , the Custom SQL should hit the connected Database that contains the data and display the computed data on Tableau.

Here the average is calculated based on the division of sum and count and should only be computed for the date value that has been selected.

The Custom SQL Query option in Tableau is not able to fulfill this requirement.
Not sure if we are doing it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a date parameter in Tableau and pass that as your User_Input. Type your query and click "Insert Parameter". Set the parameter Data type to Date and provide a current value. Insert it where needed in your query.

[image]

Comment: Hi Bernardo..Thanks for the response. In our case the Custom Query would be published to the Tableau Server and the actual value of the parameter would not be available at this point. At the time when the user accesses the report, he would make the date selection and that value is expected to replace the parameter string in the Custom SQL and computation would happen at run time.

Comment: I'm not sure you can leave the date blank until the user selects one. Otherwise just pick a dummy date.